# How to connect two Routers using Static Routes?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, routing, wireless-router

I have two Routers one being the Dlink DSL-2750U and the other Digisol DG-HR3400 having lan addresses at 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.2.1 respectively. The two routers are connected to each other from their lan ports.
Im connected to the Digisol Router with an IP Address 192.168.2.XX and Gateway 192.168.2.1. My intention is to reach the Dlink router from the PC but since their subnets are different a connection(ping for example) wouldn't be possible..
So could this be achieved using Static Routing to reach the Dlink Lan Network??

Comment: You can achieve static routes usually through the **WAN** port on most residential routers. Is there any specific reason you are not just bridging them?

Comment: set the mask on all devices to 255.255.252.0, then you should be able to ping it directly.

Comment: In general yes, if you can add the network to the routing table in both routers. That said, your setup does not seem very standards compliant. Why is it set up that way?